# How can we turn $V = \begin{bmatrix} 0 + x_2 + x_3\\x_1 + 0 + x_3 \\x_1 + x_2 + 0 \end{bmatrix}$ into a vector multiply by a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $V = \begin{bmatrix} 0 + x_2 + x_3\\x_1 + 0 + x_3 \\x_1 + x_2 + 0 \end{bmatrix}$

What is a way to decompose this vector into a vector multiplying a matrix? i.e. $V = M x$, where $ x = [x_1, x_2, x_3]^T$

Comment: I downvote the question since it is from the basics of the linear algebra and every course in linear algebra begins with this.

Comment: @Pekov Yes but it is 4 AM and I am seeing double

Comment: Consider taking a brake ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M = \left[\begin{matrix}
 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right]
$
$x = [x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}]$
then
$$Mx^{T}$$

Answer (score 4):

The coefficients of the components are the entries of the matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 + x_2 + x_3\\x_1 + 0 + x_3 \\x_1 + x_2 + 0 \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&1\\
1&0&1\\
1&1&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$